# How to debug "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)" in Python?

Tags: python

```
sentence = "ask not what your country can do for you".upper()

uniquewords = sentence.split(' ')
wordlist = []
positionlist = []

for i in uniquewords:
    if i not in wordlist:
        wordlist.append(uniquewords)
    positionlist.append(str(wordlist.index(uniquewords)+1))

joinlist = " ".join(list[i-1] for i in positionlist)
```

There is an error at the joinlist variable, this is the syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 12, in <module>
    joinlist = " ".join(list[i-1] for i in positionlist)
  File "temp.py", line 12, in <genexpr>
    joinlist = " ".join(list[i-1] for i in positionlist)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I cannot get my code to work even though I have attempted to resolve the problem multiple times.

Comment: That title will earn you lots of downvotes - please always use useful titles, and remove "please help me" fluff. If all titles were "please help me fix this", we might as well do away with titles entirely. Thanks.

Comment: In positionlist you are storing strings.
Now when you writing "for i in positionlist", your "i" is a string, but you are doing "list[i-1]", i.e. you are subtracting integer from string which is not possible :)

Comment: Invalid errand types? Like fetching more elbow grease?

Comment: @PeterWood: have you got me that packet of striped lawn seed yet?

Comment: cheers for the help boys, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line:

```
joinlist = " ".join(list[i-1] for i in positionlist)
```

The error says:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

The value of `i` is a string (it's of type `str`), and you are subtracting `1`. For example in the interactive prompt:

```
>>> '1' - 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

`i` shouldn't really be a string, but you make it so with this line:

```
positionlist.append(str(wordlist.index(uniquewords)+1))
```

Change that to:

```
positionlist.append(wordlist.index(uniquewords)+1)
```

and you should be onto the next error (c:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

from this expression:

```
list[i-1]
```

What is `list` meant to be? That's for you to work out and answer for yourself.